# How do I go about getting the average price and sum?

Tags: sql

[This the problem/data I'm working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0BTT.jpg)

I really don't know how to go about this. The class I'm taking is an online course so talking to the professor face to face is not an option.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
SELECT ProductID, SpecialOfferID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

This is what I've come up with so far, but obviously it isn't right. How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `AVG` and `SUM` functions and `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select ProductID, SpecialOfferID, AVG(AveragePrice), sum(SubTotal) 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by ProductID, SpecialOfferID
```

Comment: SELECT ProductID, SpecialOfferID, AVG(UnitPrice) doesn't seem to work. What's wrong with this? I followed the W3 Schools site.

Comment: When I tried that it seems that I'm getting an error. 

EDIT: Nevermind, I got the Average Price to work. I don't believe the names are actually Average Price and Sum, I have to check within the database I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem

```
 select ProductID,SpecialOfferId, avg(AveragePrice),sum(SubTotal) from
 SAles.SalesOrderDetail group by ProductID,SpecialOfferID
```